# How to Store Base 64 Image into Database, and to My Server Folder

Tags: javascript, php, html5-canvas

How Can I Store a Base 64 Image to my Database and To my Server Folder. the Following Code is Using to Save that Image into My server Folder. but the image can't open.

```
          $data = $src;


        $data = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $data);

          $data = str_replace(' ', '+', $data);

        $data = base64_decode($data);

         $file = '../emailtest'.rand() . '.png';

      $success = file_put_contents($file, $data);

      $data = base64_decode($data); 

       $source_img = imagecreatefromstring($data);

    $rotated_img = imagerotate($source_img, 90, 0); 

    $file = '../emailtest'. rand(). '.png';

     $imageSave = imagejpeg($rotated_img, $file, 10);

        imagedestroy($source_img);
```

Comment: I want to Save a Base64 Image to My server Folder and need to Save the Path to my Database.

Answer (score -1):

My advice:
1. Avoid to save binary to database, save it into file if possible.
2. Prefer to save binary into blob column better than save base64 into text column. Because base64 encode make this more bigger

Here is, i try to 
1. download image from url
2. save binary into file
3. save binary to db
4. convert image binary to base64
5. display image base64 using html <*img> tag

try this code
[DEMO](http://simonita.org/stackoverflow/40372733-store-image-as-base64/)

```
<?php
$img_url = 'http://cdn-o7.outfit7.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Icon-r-512-3.png';
$img_binary = file_get_contents($img_url);
$ext = pathinfo($img_url, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$img_base64 = "data:image/".$ext.";base64," . base64_encode($img_binary);

//save into file
$name = "emailtest_".rand().$ext;
file_put_contents($name, $img_binary);
echo "<img src=\"$name\" title=\"show from file\"/>";

//store to db
/* create your new table for testing
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table_img` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `img_binary` blob NOT NULL,
  `location` varchar(150) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
*/
$insert="INSERT INTO table_img ('img_binary','location') VALUES('$img_binary','$name')"; //==>save to db using this query
$select="SELECT img_binary FROM table_img WHERE id=1"; //call your image binary using this query
// then convert binary into base64 with this : $img_base64= base64_encode(YOUR BINARY DATA FROM DATABASE); 

//because i cant do it live in my server, i will shortcut call previous variable $img_base64 from above instead call binary from db and base64 encode 
echo "<img src=\"$img_base64\" title=\"show from base64\"/>";

?>
```

Comment: I need to Save the Image into Server Folder

Comment: file_get_contents then file_put_contents. or you can use ftp_put. search about php ftp

Comment: if u want complete answer. please edit your question. i answer your question with simple answer because you write the simple question